# Market as a single game or as a studio?

Tags: marketing

I'm creating an RPG with a theme of a hero that must restore peace to a world fallen to evil forces. It serves as an educational tool.

I'm creating a promotional website for it and using other online social tools for marketing.

I only have one focus: to make this game as great as possible for people to learn. I've seen some companies that market themselves as their product name, like `DuoLingo`, and some that market as the studio, such as `Strawberry Games`.

I don't have a game studio and have simply been marketing (FB page, website URL, etc) as the game's name, `Lexicana's Destiny`.

Does it really matter which way I market it? If so, why?

Comment: As a FYI, I'd like to point you at the thingy called "Universe Sandbox". Please study their case, they have rich web pages and focus on the educational side. Some 10 years ago Dixon was probably in the situation you might be in now.
http://universesandbox.com/
(google: dan dixon)

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to make this game stand out, then always go with a studio or company. It not only makes your life easier if you go to court for something (the name "the guy who made Lexicana's Destiny" sounds stupid), like when someone steals your assets, but it also makes future investors more willing to invest into your future projects.

Answer (score 1):

Marketing as a single game :

- Easier for your players to find you
- The single game will likely be more promoted

Marketing as a studio :

- More professional
- Easier to market your other games

Answer (score 0):

Going as a studio can be helpful since if you want to make a sequel or a different game series. That way people will recognize that one developer than different developers.

But, if you do NOT plan on sequels or other games, going by the name of your game will work.